# Android: customize application's menu (e.g background color)

Tags: android, customization, android-menu

What is the way (if there is a way) to customize the menu (the one triggered by the MENU button of the phone). I'm especially interested in two things:

- changing the background color from the standard light gray into a darker gray
- how the menu items are aligned. I have 4 items and they are automatically aligned 2x2, but I would prefer to have them all in one line (1x4)

Comment: Now, this question is old, but for those looking to customise **Action Bar overflow** menu background colour (say, on Android 4.0+), see this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20077381/56285

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not with the built-in menu framework.

You are welcome to intercept the MENU button (via `onKeyDown()` or something) and render what you want, but bear in mind that users will be expecting it to look like the rest of the menus do on their device.

Comment: Thanks. Then I will skip on this for now and maybe implement it at a later point when there's more time.

Comment: i have seen custom arrangements of menus (as seen here http://androidandme.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/05.categories_optionmenu.jpg ) 

so there must be a way to do it.

Answer (score 13):

I created my own menu class.  It maybe isn't exactly what you want but it should hopefully get you started.  Here is the article I published and a downloadable link to the source code.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidMenusMyWay.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You can also just implement the "onCreateOptionsMenu" method, that is usually used to display the standard menu, and display whatever you want in this case.

In my game, I implemented it to display a "Game Paused" dialog box when the menu button is pressed...

Answer (score 4):

Use styles.
This works for me on Android 5.0

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.MyStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu.MyStyle" parent="android:Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/actionbar_item_background</item>
</style>
```

... then the drawable is a regular selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/primary"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/highlighted" android:state_pressed="true"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 2):

background menu color in style.xml
in your theme

```
<item name="android:panelFullBackground">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6211536/615306) works but crashed for me when using ActionBarSherlock. Here's a hacky workaround to make this work nontheless.

```
    // Black Vodoo! Do not try this at home.

    final LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();

    final Class<LayoutInflater> clazz = LayoutInflater.class;

    try {
        final Field fieldSet = clazz.getDeclaredField("mFactorySet");
        fieldSet.setAccessible(true);
        fieldSet.setBoolean(li, false);

        li.setFactory(new Factory() {

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(final String name,
                    final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView")) {
                    try {
                        final LayoutInflater f = getLayoutInflater();
                        final View view = f.createView(name, null, attrs);
                        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // Set the text color
                                ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            }
                        });
                        return view;
                    } catch (final Exception e) {
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```