# Android: how do i custom arrange menu items?

Tags: android, menu

I would like to arrange the menu items in my app so that one item appears in its own line, and  the other 3 items appear below it. I know that this is possible because i have seen apps do it. I tried writing a menu xml with linear layouts to arrange the items, but this doesnt work. I have also tried putting them in different groups, but I had no luck with that either.

I know that this is possible: i have seen it done.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean item below other items? A submenu?

Comment: This is similar to what i want to do: http://androidandme.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/05.categories_optionmenu.jpg 

notice that one menu item has an entire row to itself. that's what i want. however, android defaults to 2x2 for 4 items and 3x1 for 3 items.

Comment: like this http://androidandme.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/05.categories_optionmenu.jpg

Comment: Kindof a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593529/android-customize-applications-menu-e-g-background-color