# Custom options menu in Android

Tags: android, options-menu

I want to create a custom `OptionsMenu` in my application. The default `OptionsMenu` display only three items in one row. Now i want to display five to six items having only icons. Also i want to change the background color of the OptionsMenu but not getting the appropriate way of doing this. If it is possible then please let me know about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**

As an user it bothers me when the application changes my android's widgets. I wouldn't recommend changing that and android doesn't provide a way to do it.

**Long answer**

Even though Android doesn't provide a way to customize that you can always handle the key event and show a view from your own. [Similar discussion in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1593529/119895).