# Android Option Menu

Tags: android

I am creating Option menu items that includes four menus in it. I wanna to display the menus in the List order from top to bottom (i.e)

```
Menu 1

Menu 2

Menu 3

Menu 4
```

Not like:

```
 menu 1 | menu 2 | menu 3 | menu 4
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Take a look at this question, you might get answer:

[Custom options menu in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193348/how-to-create-custom-options-menu-in-android)