# Making game like menu in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to cope with some problem in finding good idea. I would like to make interesting menu like in games on Android (eg. ANngry Birds or here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q3g6SdTODY4) In this panda game I supose that first menu are simply 3 color buttons, but what about this sliding menu later with stages description - this same as in angry birds? Telling the truth I have got no idea what object it can be?

I will be glad if someone can tell me that. Or the best to give some tutorials about it. I cant google any.

Comment: "I cant google any." Why? lol

Comment: Try [this link](http://googleitfor.me/?q=android+custom+options+menu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems that this sliding stage description is implemented with some simple layout placed to [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) and some [animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/animation.html) applied to the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

It can be your custom view provided with your translation animations and handling its visibility on the click of the default menu button (via onKeyDown()) on Android.

Comment: I see you don't get what I meant. Did you check those games? I don't mean menu opened after MENU key pressed. I mean onscreen menu where you can choose for example start, level or something like that.

Comment: @sebap123, looks like you didn't get the answer.

Comment: oh common, if that is what you are asking, I wud say its simply playing with the layout positions and animations (translations). One can use "view stub" also.
There is a lot of stuff already provided by Android to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

There are similar questions:

[Custom options menu in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193348/custom-options-menu-in-android)

[Android: customize application's menu (e.g background color)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593529/android-customize-applications-menu-e-g-background-color)

Comment: I see you don't get what I meant. Did you check those games? I don't mean menu opened after MENU key pressed. I mean onscreen menu where you can choose for example start, level or something like that.