# Re-arrange the context options menu order

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I have a context option menu, that I need to re-arrange it in a specific order.
Every row of the option menu should contain only a single item, like Share to Fb, and Share to Twitter are now displayed.

Is it possible to make the option menu "Some warning text..."  and "Logout" be on separate rows?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You're using default options menu the answer seems to be 'no'. Android decides itself on placing options.

Probably, You might need to create custom options menu. Please, refer to [this guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/173121/Android-Menus-My-Way) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193348/custom-options-menu-in-android) already asked.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement Custom options menu then you  make static text. here is some reference link for Custom options menu ,http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/173121/Android-Menus-My-Way