# Android Menu Items

Tags: android

Can you set the number of menu items per line? At the moment it is 2 by 2 but could I have 3 and 1 large underneath?

If this is possible how would I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you can do this by using Groups.  Have a look at that in the groupId argument when yo create the menus.

Comment: No, its no possible with groups. Only way to do is to develop your own custom menus. See this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593529/android-customize-applications-menu-e-g-background-color