# "expandable" menu to the right - Android \ Java

Tags: java, android, drop-down-menu, menu

I know it's not a legitimate question but I'm searching an example to this menu for Android\Java about 2.5 hours and I'm lost. **Please just give me a link or write me its name** so I can google it, find examples and implement it by myself.

I just saw that many people use sliding menu or dropdown menu but it's different than what I want I guess.

[image: two muppets]
<sub>(source: [smashingmagazine.com](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/flyouts.jpg))</sub>

Comment: It's not ExpandableListView either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of those is a spinner, so I thought it might be called an expandable spinner, and got some hits for what you're trying to do : [expandable-spinner : How to implement expandable spinner entry in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828938/expandable-spinner-how-to-implement-expandable-spinner-entry-in-android)

Another term for it might be "multi-level spinner" for which there are more hits similar to what you want. [Best practices for implementing a multi-level Option Menu on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412822/best-practices-for-implementing-a-multi-level-option-menu-on-android)

I'm not sure this is the best approach for a menu, though. Would you consider something like this instead: https://github.com/pratikbutani/MultiSelectSpinner

Comment: The first link looks the same!
After reading your last paragraph, I guess I'll implement something else because I read more recommendations for such a menu.

so probably I'll use this: 
http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.co.il/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html