# Android - Remove/Add padding between buttons on AtionBarCompat

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-actionbar

I am using the ActionBar Compatibility, everything is OK, except the fact that by default, the buttons (actions) have some padding around.

How can I alter that padding for specific buttons, remove it, and in some cases adjust.
[image]

Comment: How are you adding the buttons.  In the past in order to change attributes within (essentially) a menu with custom buttons, spacing etc... I have had to build my own menu.  Some good links are here at the following StackOverflow question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593529/android-customize-applications-menu-e-g-background-color

Comment: The buttons are inflated from a menu.xml resource, just like any other regular options menu. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I have read the examples. Well, with the options menu it seems to be more easier to adapt, than with ActionBar, my case.

Comment: do you have your menu.xml code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by creating a custom layout and attaching it to the ActionBar, by configuring the styles:

```
<style name="ActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
   <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo|showCustom</item>
   <item name="android:customNavigationLayout">@layout/actionbar_custom_title</item>
</style>
```

Now there appeared another problem: Please see this thread if you can help me: [Android - Remove "More actions" button from the ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961107/android-remove-more-actions-button-from-the-actionbar)