# Android - Remove "More actions" button from the ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an ActionBar that should display the action buttons in a custom way. For this I created a custom view and attached it to the ActionBar.

One thing to mention is that I am using a **menu.xml** resoure file to load the options menu and display them on a smartphone, but do not display them on tablet, instead use a custom view. For this I market every menu item in the xml as: `android:showAsAction="never"`

Everything looks fine, except one little  thing that still remains on the right of the ActionBar - the "More" button.

How can I remove it?

[image]

I tried this:

```
ActionBar bar = activity.getActionBar();
bar.removeAllTabs();
```

but the "more" button still remains there.

**EDIT:**
This is my menu.xml file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_username"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_username"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/menu_username">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_logout"
                android:title="@string/menu_logout"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_search"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/menu_search"/>

</menu>
```

**Please note I still want to inflate this menu on a smartphone, but don't want to use it on a tablet.**

Comment: That should only appear in your action bar if you have items in it. Please post your `menu.xml` resource and where/how you are using it. Also, this has nothing to do with tabs in the action bar, which is why your `removeAllTabs()` call had no effect -- this is not a tab, but the overflow affordance.

Comment: What that says is "I want all three items to be in the overflow". This is why I asked you to show where/how you are using that resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `showAsAction="never"` will force an menu item into the overflow. Why not check in onCreateOptionsMenu(...) that the device is a tablet, and if it is just not inflate the menu? Something like this:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().smallestScreenWidthDp >= 600) {
        //It's a tablet, don't inflate, only create the manual view
        manualMenuCreation();
    } else {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Don't forget `smallestScreenWidthDp` is only available in 3.2 or above, so you'll have to take that into consideration.

Comment: I know its an old answer but please tell me what is this method manualMenuCreation()?