# How to change Options menu dots color?

Tags: android, colors, menu

I want to change Options menu's dots color to white. I tried to add image for this but dose not work. How to do this?

[image]

menu xml :

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout.Main2Activity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_more_vert_white_48dp"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Put it in your `style.xml` in `AppTheme`:

```
<!-- android:textColorSecondary is the color of the menu overflow icon (three vertical dots) -->
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
```

Comment: easiest one.. Thank you..@ayz4sci

Comment: Put it in your style.xml. AppTheme.

Comment: my theme is Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar. And this doesn't works for me. Can you help me?

Comment: @HariKrishnan did you get any solution on this?

Comment: no. what i have done is added an icon with the color i wanted  there

Comment: @HariKrishnan how can i  overcome it.thanks in advance

Comment: It also changes color of Radio Buttons, which is not required by most of the people. I guess.

Comment: Thank you @ayz4sci...sort and simple solution...!!!

Comment: Doesn't work at all

Comment: @zulkarnainshah did you end up finding a solution that works? This is driving me crazy trying to get it to work.

Comment: @AlexF Not Yet. still have the black dots :(

Comment: @zulkarnainshah check out the answer here by Barun Kumar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425660/change-color-of-the-overflow-button-on-actionbar/36278375#comment82685074_36278375. Worked for me.

Comment: doesn't work for standart ActionBar of `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

Comment: it works for me.

Comment: I think this only works if you're using your own `toolbar` (worked for me, didn't work with default action bar). Also `@color/white` should be `@android:color/white`.

Comment: @user924 same here not working with `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: This didnt work for me because I was using action bar. So this helped me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56300566/1465756

Comment: You should add this to your ToolbarTheme in styles.xml

Answer (score 21):

You can change the image used for it using the following style declaration.

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="style/Theme.Holo">
<item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyCustomTheme.OverFlow</item>

</style>

<style name="MyCustomTheme.OverFlow">
<item name="android:src">@drawable/my_overflow_image</item>

</style>
```