# Android Actionbar Options Menu Color Change

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a custom theme for my android app. I have to change the options menu color, now it is white dots. I have to change the color to red.

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle" tools:targetApi="23">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle" tools:targetApi="23">@style/ActionBarTabText
    </item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/vkcred</item>
    <!--<item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerIcon</item>-->

    <item name="android:popupBackground" tools:targetApi="23">@color/home_list_color</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor" tools:targetApi="23">@color/action_bar_title</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/PopupWrapper</item>
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/menuCustomMenuTextApearance</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTabText</item>

    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/action_bar_title</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/Widget.ActionButton.Overflow</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.ActionButton.Overflow" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:contentDescription">@string/accessibility_overflow</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/PopupMenuListView</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupWrapper" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenuStyle</item>
</style>
<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">


    <item name="android:titleTextStyle" tools:targetApi="23">@style/ActionBarTitleText</item>
    <!--  <item name="android:background" tools:targetApi="11">@drawable/titlebar</item> -->
    <item name="android:popupBackground" tools:targetApi="23">@color/home_list_color</item>
    <!-- <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>-->
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTitleText</item>
    <!--<item name="background">@color/white</item>-->


</style>

<!-- ActionBar title text -->
<style name="ActionBarTitleText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/action_bar_title</item>
    <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
</style>

<!-- ActionBar tabs text -->
<style name="ActionBarTabText" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/action_bar_title</item>
    <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
</style>
```

Actually I have to change the option menu color to red. As I am new to the theme change using styles, I was unable to find what the issue is. Hi I am not using a toolbar instead using getSupportActionBar().Please help me in resolving this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the Action Bar Overflow button color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35932669/how-do-i-change-the-action-bar-overflow-button-color)

Comment: Do you have an `AppBarLayout` or `CollapsingToolbarLayout`?

Answer (score 0):

Inside style.xml change your colorPrimary and colorSecondary to red and slightly red ,

You can find the material pallets  on https://www.materialpalette.com
Download the style.xml and paste in your res folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your `CustomActionBarTheme`:

```
<!-- android:textColorSecondary is the color of the menu overflow icon (three vertical dots) -->
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/red</item>
```

And change parent theme to :

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Try once again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="MyToolbarTheme">
    <!-- Used to tint the back arrow, menu and spinner arrow -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#EF5350</item> //red
</style>

<Toolbar
    android:theme="@style/MyToolbarTheme"
    .../>
```

You can set theme programmatically like this

```
getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext().setTheme(R.style.MyToolbarTheme);
```

Comment: You will use this after setting toolbar.

Comment: I dont have any toolbar in my App. I have to  change the option menu (The three dots) color without using any ToolBar

Comment: A little change use `getThemedContext()` instead of `getContext()`, I changed in answer too.

Comment: I have tested and provided you. I extend AppCompactActivity. what do you extend?