# How to change the color of the overflow button (3 vertical dots) and text color of ToolbarItem on the ActionBar?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-actionbar, toolbar

I want to change the color of the `ToolbarItem` and the overflow button (3 vertical dots). As I have found out the `colorPrimaryDark` is responsible for both. If I change the color also the color of the dots or `ToolbarItem` text color changes. But changing `colorPrimaryDark` leads to modifications in my generall app for all sorts of elements.

How do I change the color specifically for the items in the `ActionBar`?

Here I define *AppTheme* for my app in *MainActivity.cs*:

```cs
[Activity(Theme = "@style/AppTheme", ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
{
    // ...    
}
```

In *themes_apptheme.xml* under *Resources/values* I have defined my *AppTheme*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
        <!-- ... -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

In *styles.xml* under *Resources/values* there is the referenced *MyActionBarTheme*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_back</item>
        <!--<item name="android:background">@color/primaryDark</item>-->
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/primaryDark</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I've tried the solutions from the similar questions (e.g. `textColorSecondary`), but non of them worked or specifically targets my needs. For the dots an image could be used, but that doesn't change the color of `ToolbarItem` and seems not to be necessary. Also other solutions are using the newer `Toolbar` instead of the `ActionBar`. Furthermore the themes are different. Can I somehow use a custom renderer? Or would it be sufficient to add one item to my style? Which one is it?

PS: I'm using Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0.121934

**Edit:**

My goal is to have a white color for the overflow button and the `ToolbarItem` text. This can be achived, if I use the following:

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- ... -->
</style>
```

The downside of this approach is, that the background of `ContextAction` is black and I don't know how to change the color (as before with the dots and the toolbar button). Styling in Android is a big hassle for me.

Comment: I think overflow button is a image icon which you need to choose what color you want.

Comment: @CGPA6.4: When I change the `textColorPrimary` the "*image*" color changes too. Don't know how this happens. For me it seems like it would be a `TextView`.

Comment: Visit this might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35932669/how-do-i-change-the-action-bar-overflow-button-color

Comment: @CGPA6.4: Tried the first two solutions without success. I added them to the file, where `AppTheme` is defined. The used theme in most answers is different from mine.

Comment: In your android project resource folder you have Toolbar axml file. Apply newly created Style on that. in xaml file itself.

Comment: That is the thing. I use `ActionBar`, not `Toolbar`. Therefore I have no *Toolbar.xml*  file. Perhaps I have to switch to `Toolbar`. FYI: I edited my question.