# How to change the background of menu items in Android when they are clicked

Tags: android, menu, background, click

how do I change the background of menu items in Android when they are clicked. The problem is sometimes the background is gray (as it should be) and sometimes it's blue.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Hopefully this will clear things up. I made two screen shots. The [first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdOgQ.png) shows the menu on the first click. The [second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hd99A.png) shows the click after I closed the menu and opened again. As you can see the item background is suddenly blue. How do I change that behavior?

Code for menu:

```
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getContext(), view);
popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.food_context_menu);
popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(...);
popupMenu.show();
```

Menu layout:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_add_to_journal"
        android:title="@string/food_action_add_to_journal"
        app:showAsAction="withText" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_edit"
        android:title="@string/food_action_edit"
        app:showAsAction="withText" />
</menu>
```

Style:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Your question is so poor. You did not add any code, the questions is not precise.. You invested 0 effort asking us. Did you mean [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659637/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-action-bars-option-menu-in-android-4-2) ?

Comment: you want it in navigation drawer?

Comment: @UDKOX I think he wants to change the background color when user click on it before performing the clicked operation.

Comment: many time i got this type error and it it 99% of he is using dialog

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036204/change-the-action-bar-settings-icon-color/16036350#16036350

Comment: I don't want to change the background of the menu. I want to change the background of the menu items when they are clicked. Per default I got the behavior that it is sometimes blue and the other time it's gray. I got that with any kind of menu: PopupMenu, OptionsMenu, NavigationView, etc.