# Android Context Menu Edittext Background Color

Tags: android

I'm looking for an Option to design the context menu for an edit text.
So, if you have an `Activity` with an `Edittext` and you make a long click on it, at the top of the screen the context menu (containing cut, copy, ...) pops up.
How can I change the Background color?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

If I change it to

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

The menu gets a dark background instead

What style attribute I have to change to set it to e.g. orange?

Comment: You should rather use an ActionMode IMHO. Anyway, what "background color" are you referring to?

Comment: @shkschneider: the background of the context menu poping up if you long click on an edittext

Comment: You would need to provide some code here...

Comment: There is no code right now. It's just an edittext. And I don't know how to set the background from the menu poping up between the Android statusbar and the actionbar of my app. (cut, copy, ...)

Comment: Ah ok, got it all wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19659779/603270 https://stackoverflow.com/a/1596453/603270

Comment: Edited the question. Tried your links but didn't work out.